# How process data send from a .findAll(include: {all: true}) of sequelize

Tags: reactjs, foreach, sequelize.js, array.prototype.map

I have some difficulties to get value in my array. On my server side, I use sequelize to get my value from my tables with the command `include: {all: true}` :

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const listOfGovernments = await GovernmentCreate.findAll({
        include: {all: true}
    });
    res.json(listOfGovernments);
});
```

See below the Json response that send my server :

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, createdAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z', updatedAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z', Justices: Array(1), Interieurs: Array(1), …}
1: {id: 2, createdAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:21.000Z', updatedAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:21.000Z', Justices: Array(1), Interieurs: Array(1), …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

[image]

As you can see, it send my `Array` in my Json response *(`Justices: Array(1)`, `Interieurs: Array(1)`, etc...)*. It is because my tables Justices and Interieurs are associates with my main tables :

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
AffaireEtrangeres: [{…}]
Agricultures: [{…}]
Armees: [{…}]
Cultures: [{…}]
Ecologies: [{…}]
EconomieFinances: [{…}]
EducationNationales: [{…}]
Interieurs: [{…}]
Justices: [{…}]
OutreMers: [{…}]
Santes: [{…}]
Sports: [{…}]
Travails: [{…}]
createdAt: "2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z"
id: 1
updatedAt: "2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {id: 2, createdAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:21.000Z', updatedAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:21.000Z', Justices: Array(1), Interieurs: Array(1), …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I click on my tables Justices and Interieurs attibutes to watch more informations that the serve send to me. They containes `firstName`, `LastName` and other informations. That is normal because it is the data in entrance when I created my data base :

[image]

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
AffaireEtrangeres: [{…}]
Agricultures: [{…}]
Armees: [{…}]
Cultures: [{…}]
Ecologies: [{…}]
EconomieFinances: [{…}]
EducationNationales: [{…}]
Interieurs: Array(1)
0: {id: 1, firstName: 'interieur', lastName: 'interieurNom', createdAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z', updatedAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z', …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
Justices: Array(1)
0: {id: 1, firstName: 'justice', lastName: 'justiceNom', createdAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z', updatedAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z', …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
OutreMers: [{…}]
Santes: [{…}]
Sports: [{…}]
Travails: [{…}]
createdAt: "2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z"
id: 1
updatedAt: "2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {id: 2, createdAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:21.000Z', updatedAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:21.000Z', Justices: Array(1), Interieurs: Array(1), …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

**So, my question is :** how I can do to add `firstName` and `lastName` value of each attributs *(Justices, Interieurs, etc...)* from my index 0... with en function `.map()` or `.forEach()` *(or anything else...)* in a `span` tag ?
Then, repeat this action for index 1, index 2, etc...

I take time to asking this question because I spent all my day to find the good wath without success. I hope someone will help me.

```
import React from 'react';

const exemple = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            { //myJsonResponse.map() or .forEach() => {
                (
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            //Span tag that containe value of firstName from attribut Justice[i] from index[i]
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            //Span tag that containe value of lastName from attribut Justice[i] from index[i]
                        </span>
                    </div>
                )
            )};
        </div>
    );
};

export default exemple;
```

*************** Answer to Sumanth Madishetty ****************

To answer of the proposition below I did a console.log() :

```
{governmentList.map((responseItem) => {
                console.log(responseItem)
                return Object.values(responseItem).map((i) => {
                    console.log(i)
                    console.log(i[0])
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <span>{i[0].firstName}</span>
                            <span>{i[0].lastName}</span>
                        </div>
                    )
                });
            }
            )};
```

And my console show me :
[image]

Comment: just to clarify, you will be having a object of { a: [{ firstName: "fir", "lastName": "las" }], b: [ { firstName: "firasdad", "lastName": "laasds" }]  } and you need a function. to print first name in first element of a, b, etccc right??

Comment: Exactly @SumanthMadishetty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of your requirement you can try this

Assuming you have response in variable `response`

```
response.map((responseItem) => {
  return Object.values(responseItem).map((i) => {
    // Object.values returns the value of each item in the object like [{firstName: "", ...}, { "firstName": "" }] here the firstname in the first element will be of Justices, 2nd will be of sports etc, according to your response
    return (
      <div>
      <span>
          {i[0].firstName}
      </span>
      <span>
      {i[0].lastName}
      </span>
  </div>
    )
  })
})
```

Please go through the codesandbox for better understanding https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-bardeen-m0dhzw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the demo. Unfortunalty I got a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstName')`. I don't know what is the reason because I follow your exemple.

Comment: I update my post to show you with a `console.log()` what I got;

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution with the exemple of @SumanthMadishetty. In my case, I have to add `?` before my properties because I have some case where my firstName or lastName doesn't exist.
Check the code below :

```
{governmentList.map((responseItem) => {
                    return Object.values(responseItem).map((i) => {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <span>{i[0]?.firstName}</span>
                                <span>{i[0]?.lastName}</span>
                            </div>
                        )
                    });
                }
                )};
```